# Check if local date time exist NODA TIME

Tags: c#, nodatime

Is there a way to validate the date time if it does exist?

this might sound weird but if you apply daytime saving to a certain zone for example America/New_york March 12. 2017 2am to 3am is their daylight saving time. literary speaking from March 12. 2017 2am to 2:59am it doesn't exist in their time. i wanna validate a given date time if it exist

i tried using this

**given dateTime = March 12. 2017 2:30am**

```
 var timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/New_York"); 
 var localDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
 var result = timeZoneProvider.AtStrictly(localDate).ToDateTimeUtc();
```

it throws and error is there a way to validate it before using AtStrictly? that where it throws error and says the date time doesn't not exist this is due to DayLight Saving in that zone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DateTimeZone.MapLocal` method can give you this information.  Here are some extension methods that will make this easy.  (Put them in a static class somewhere.)

```
public static bool IsInvalidTime(this DateTimeZone tz, LocalDateTime ldt)
{
    return tz.MapLocal(ldt).Count == 0;
}

public static bool IsAmbiguousTime(this DateTimeZone tz, LocalDateTime ldt)
{
    return tz.MapLocal(ldt).Count > 1;
}
```

Then you can do things like this in the spring:

```
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2017, 3, 12, 2, 30);

if (timeZone.IsInvalidTime(localDateTime)) { ... true ... }
```

and in the fall:

```
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2017, 11, 5, 1, 30);

if (timeZone.IsAmbiguousTime(localDateTime)) { ... true ... }
```

Of course, this assumes you just want to pre-validate.  If you wanted to actually apply some conversion rules, thats where `AtLeniently` or `ResolveLocal(... your custom rules ...)` would come in.